# ABCD is a square. A point M is taken on side CD...

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$  is a square. A point  $M$ is taken on the side $CD$; $K$ is the point of intersection of the side $BC$ and the bisector of the $\angle{BAM}.$  Prove that $MA=BK+DM $.

I found this on a question paper, and I have no idea how to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $E$ a point in the side $CD$ such that $AE$ is perpendicular to $AK$. You need to prove that $\triangle AME$ is isosceles.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it will be a great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a point $P$on the line $CD$ (extended) Let the angle bisector be $AP$ (of $\angle BAM$) so $P$ is outside of DC such that $CP=DM$.Now we can easily see that $BP$ is parallel to $AM$.$AP$ is cutting $BC$ on $K$ .Now by corresponding angle $$\angle MAK=\angle CKP$$ and by alternate angle
$$\angle CPK=\angle PAB$$ and Since $$\angle MAK=\angle PAB$$
so $$\angle CKP=\angle CPK\implies CK=CP\implies BC=BK+KC \implies BC=BK+CP$$$$\implies BC=BK+DM$$.